# Cannot find shared object in LD_LIBRARY_PATH ( Amazon Linux )

Tags: aws-lambda, linker, shared-libraries, ldd

I have a python runtime on aws lambda. As there known issue that ghostscript is broken on aws lambda ami ( in my case its amazon linux because of python 3.7 ). So i collected whatever so's that are missing on ami and grouped it with package. The next step was to set

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /tmp/project/ghostscript/
```

Now, when i run

```
print(os.listdir(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']))
```

I get

```
['libjbig.so.0', 'libpaper.so.1', 'libijs-0.35.so', 'libgs.so', 'libfreetype.so.6', 'libfontconfig.so.1', 'libtiff.so.5', 'libjbig2dec.so.0', 'libidn.so.11', 'libjpeg.so.8']
```

So far so good, now when I manually do

```
print(ctypes.util.find_library('gs'))
```

I get

```
'libgs.so'
```

Still looking good. Next step is loading library so

```
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libgs.so')
```

and it breaks

```
OSError: libgs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now, as i understand dlopen on linux goes by order (not mentioning conditions) rpath -> ld_library_path -> runpath -> cache -> usr/lib etc. So why can't it find my so.

So in order to test, I changed the soname of the libgs.so to /tmp/project/ghostscript/libgs.so and it loads (because of the abs path) but failing to link one of its needed with same error.

The last two steps are from third-party module so changing it is not a good option. I think LD_LIBRARY_PATH is being ignored. Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: The standard Ghostscript build includes its required 3rd party libraries statically, so it can't fail 'to link one of its needed'. If you've built Ghostscript to use shared system libraries, then rebuild it and use statically linked ones. That will get rid of your final problem. Other than that, this isn't a Ghostscript question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I load libgs with absolute path, it fails with OSError - libijs-0.35.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. (Removing Ghostscript tag )

Comment: @KenS will try to build, I used my system’s so and put together whatever was missing

Comment: libijs isn't used by Ghostscript, either statically or dynamically, so that OSError can't be from Ghostscript. I imagine the shared object you are using has been built to use system shared libraries as all the package maintainers do that (we don't recommend it but we have no control there). Its doubtful that any random binary wil work on a different Linux build due to ABI incompatibilities. It might, you could be lucky, but probably not. You might be better to use lambda Ghostscript which although old has been packaged for AWS (I believe).